# I would like the function where the mobile menu (Responsive Navigation) slides away or closes after a selection has been made

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like the function where the mobile menu (Responsive Navigation) slides away or closes after a selection has been made

```
$("#btn_open_menu").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $("#header").toggleClass("active");

    if ($("#header").hasClass('active')) {
        $("#header .menu_closed").css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $("#header .menu_closed").css('display', 'none');
    }

    return false;
});

//closed menu in responsive
$("#menu_closed").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $("#header").removeClass('active')
    $("#header .menu_closed").css('display', 'none');

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$(".link_menu").on("click",function(){
    $("#header").removeClass("active");
});
```